# r.object in f.fields_for |r| is nil in my rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some weird stuff going on, in my rails 4 application in a view I do:

```
<%= f.object.reply_fields.inspect %>

# prints out 4 objects

<%= f.fields_for :reply_fields do |r| %>
    <%= r.object.inspect %>
<% end %>

# prints out "nil" only once
```

I don't understand what is going on here, what can I do so it loops over the 4 objects? More info:

```
# routes

resources :invites do
  resources :replies
end

# Invite model

has_many :inputs
has_many :replies

# Reply model

belongs_to :invite
has_many :reply_fields

# ReplyField model

belongs_to :reply
belongs_to :input

# Input model

belongs_to :invite
has_many :reply_fields

# controller

def new
  @reply = Reply.new(invite: @invite)
  @invite.inputs.each do |i| # there are 4 items in there
    @reply.reply_fields.build(input:i)
  end
end

    # viev

    <%= form_for [@invite, @reply] do |f| %>
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are going to need

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :reply_fields
```

in the model.

Comment: Omg you're right, I'm such a noob, thanks! I will accept the answer as soon as it is possible.